# Did anyone was able to run ios ui test on the simulator after last 18 september 2018 releases?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest, uitest

I wrote a few ui test in March/APril using **NUunit 2.6.3** and **Xamarin.UITest 2.2.4**, and I was able to run them on debug mode using the ipad simulator on my mac and also on a physical test ipad.

Today, after last xcode , os and visual studio for mac releases, I get mainly 2 errors:

1) **not able to install the device - agent** ( i tried deleting the xdb folder inside the tmpdir folder) and then I get

2) **unable to contact test backend running app .a common cause is that the app is not properly linked with calabash**, Even if I aded xamarin cloud agent 
v 0.21.6 (also tried the last one 0.21.7 but with no success)package to my iOS app(I'm using xamarin.forms 3.1), I've added the **ENABLE_CLOUD** key for the build action, and also in the FinishedLaunching method inside AppInitializer I have Xamarin,Calabash.Start() .

Did anyone has any clue? I also tried the last version of **Xamarin.UITest 2.2.6** without any success.

Comment: From what i remember you could never run it in Debug mode, because you cant have Mono Shared Runtime enabled?

Answer (score 0):

WE solved by installing and using ios 11.4 simulator...trying to fix this also for the ios 12

Comment: I've been on teams that have downgraded xcode to solve issues with simulator/UITest and all it does is create long-term tech debt. One thing I would try...Restart the device before you run the UITests. I had a major major problem on iOS on where I needed to restart the device before running UITests or I would get a Device Agent error. Now before we run UITests, we restart the device through command line before kicking off the tests. Please restart the device before running the UITests and let me know if that works. Silly, yes but solved my issue. Also, Like @Woj said, build for Release mode

Comment: seems that installing the device agent on the 12 simulator, is crashing :(